# bash: variable outside function scope

Tags: bash

Is there a possible way to initialize a global variable in bash and assign it a value in a function, then use it out side the function scope?

Function example:

```
globla_var=""

_DBINFO()
{
  curl  -su $AUTH https://<balla bla >/databases | jq -c 'map(select(.plan.name != "Sandbox")) | .[] | {id, name}'| \
  while  read db
  do
    idb=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.id')
    name=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.name')
    if [[ $name = '<bla>' ]]; then
        $global_var_her = $(<bla value>)
     fi
  done
}
```

then use it outside the function:

```
 echo $global_var
```

the result

```
   $0: line 16: =<bla bla>: command not found
```

I tried using declare:

```
declare -r global_var
```

same results

Comment: In fact, variables in a function are global by default; local variables must be explicitly declared using either the `local` or `declare` builtins.

Comment: there is a typo at the beginning `globla_var` which should be `global_var` as I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to be careful about subshells that limit scope in unexpected ways. Piping to a `while read` loop like you are doing [is a common pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Instead of piping to a while read loop, use redirection and process substitution:

```
_DBINFO()
{     
  while read db
  do
    idb=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.id')
    name=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.name')
    if [[ $name = '<bla>' ]]; then
        global_var=value
     fi
  done  <  <(curl  -su "$AUTH" "https://$host/databases" |
               jq -c 'map(select(.plan.name != "Sandbox")) | .[] | {id, name}')
}

AUTH="user:password"
host="example.com"
_DBINFO
echo "The global variable is $global_var"
```

You also need to make sure your assignment is syntactically valid. `$var = value` is not a valid bash assignment, while `var=value` is. [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) can point out many things like that.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're confusing `bash` with `php`. Just remove the `$`, the `_her` part, and the space:

```sh
global_var=$(<bla value>) # or maybe: global_var='<bla value>'
```

instead of:

```sh
$global_var_her = $(<bla value>)
```

With that, the error goes away.

---

On the other hand, check [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33377281/4095830) regard to the pipelines.

And yes, it is possible to define a global variable and it is done the way you're doing it.

---

Maybe is useful pointing something about this:

```sh
$(<bla value>)
```

If `<bla value>` is a command, the sentence is ok, because that't the way to capture the output of a command with [`Command Substitution`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

If, instead, is a literal value, just remove the `$()` leaving just `'<bla value>'` (`global_var='<bla value>'`). This is the same to do `$(echo '<bla value>')` but that would be an unnecessary waste of resources.

Answer (score 3):

This is already answered, but I'd give it a shorter solution

```
test() { declare x="Important output"; }

test && echo $x
```

Will leave us with no output, while the answer has a workaround, here's what I suggest to use

```
test() { export x="Important output"; }

test && echo $x
```

Will give us an output

Comment: This does not address the problem at hand though - while you can read it, you still can't write to it in a way that propagates to the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

All variables have global scope, unless declared local inside some function.

So, all the vars in your program are valid outside the function.
But there are several problems:

1. You are sending the output of `curl ...` with a pipe `|`. That creates a sub-shell. Variables changed inside a sub-shell are not translated to global.
2. The name of the var was `globla_var=""`. Is that a typo? Should it be `global_var`?.
3. There is an space before and after the = in: `$global_var_her = "bla"`. That is incorrect syntax in bash, and in shell in general.
4. There is a `$` on the left side of an equality. That does not assign to the variable `global_var_her`.
5. There is an additional `_her` which seems UN-needed.

All corrected, this should work:

```
global_var=""

_DBINFO(){

    content=$(
        curl  -su $AUTH https://<balla bla >/databases |
        jq -c 'map(select(.plan.name != "Sandbox")) | .[] | {id, name}'
    )

    while  read -r db
    do
        idb=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.id')
        name=$(echo "$db" | jq -r '.name')
        if [[ $name = '<bla>' ]]; then
            global_var=$(echo "<bla value>")
        fi
    done <<<"$content"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `declare -g`. From declare help page:

```
-g  create global variables when used in a shell function; otherwise
    command.  The `-g' option suppresses this behavior.
```

```bash
f() {
    declare -g newvar="It works!";
}
f
echo $newvar;  # It works!
```